# Proof of a specific Concave Function

Tags: calculus, analysis

I'm working on a  Advanced Microeconomic Theory - Jehle, Reny's question and I can't figure out how to do it without using tools that aren't specified on the question.

Let $D = [-2, 2]$ and $f : D \to \Bbb{R}$ be $f(x) = 4 - x^2$. 
Carefully sketch this function. 
Using the definition of a concave function, prove that $f$ is concave. 
Demonstrate that the set $A$ is a convex set.

My answer:
Definition of a concave function is:
$f : D \to \Bbb{R}$ is a concave function if and only if for all $x_1$,$x_2$ $\in D$, $f(x_t) \geq tf(x_1) + (1-t) f(x_2) \forall t \in [0,1]$.

$$4 - (tx_1 + (1-t)x_2)^2 \geq t (4 - x_1^2) + ( 1 -t) (4 - x_2^2)$$

$$4 - (tx_1 + (1-t)x_2)^2 \geq 4t - x_1^2t + 4 - x_2^2 -4t +tx_2^2$$

$$- (tx_1 + (1-t)x_2)^2 \geq -t (x_1^2 - x_2^2) - x_2^2$$

But, after that I couldn't develop anything to get closer to prove it. Do you have any tips for me what I can do?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the $A$ set?

Comment: Be careful. The last term in the second inequality is $+tx_2^2$. Try expanding the left hand side also.

Comment: $A\equiv \{(x,y)|x\in D, f(x)\geq y\}$

Comment: @AugSB I fixed it!Thanks!

Comment: a) There is a 4 lost in the last ineq. on the RHS. (b) there is still a wrong sign on the RHS of the last ineq; (c) If you develop the squared term on the LHS, you can simplify and conclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following from your second inequality
$$4 - (tx_1 + (1-t)x_2)^2 \geq 4t - x_1^2t + 4 - x_2^2 - 4t + tx_2^2,$$
you get
$$ - (tx_1 + (1-t)x_2)^2 \geq - x_1^2t - x_2^2 + tx_2^2.$$
If you expand the LHS and reorder all terms, you obtain
$$ (1 - t) t (x_1 - x_2)^2 \geq 0.$$
Obviously, the equality holds for $t=0$, $t=1$ or $x_1=x_2$. In all other cases, the inequality is strict, but also true.

Regarding the convexity of
$$A=\{(x,y)|x\in D, f(x)\geq y\},$$
let $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)$ be points of $A$. For $t\in[0,1]$, we define
$$(x_t,y_t) := t(x_1,y_1) + (1-t)(x_2,y_2) = (tx_1+(1-t)x_2,ty_1+(1-t)y_2).$$
Thus, $(x_t,y_t)$ belongs to $A$ if and only if
$$f(tx_1+(1-t)x_2) \geq ty_1+(1-t)y_2.$$
You just need to apply the concavity of $f$ to conclude that the inequality is true.A